# Change checkbox skin after first init

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm loading a CheckBoxStyle from a skin:

```
chk = new CheckBox("checkbox", skin, "style1");
```

How can I change the style afterwards without having to dispose the currently loaded checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symply get the checkbox style from skin, (or create it by yourself), and then use setStyle() from checkbox class:

```
      CheckBox.CheckBoxStyle otherStyle = skin.get("style1", CheckBox.CheckBoxStyle.class);
      chk.setStyle(otherStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks! I would initiate the CheckBox every time but it wouldn't work : `chk = new CheckBox("checkbox", skin, "newstyle1");` . setStyle works though .